# Dismiss PopViewController in the last View from the collection

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I have develop an app that has a first View with a Start button. When I push the button, I start `PageViewController`. What I need is that, in the last item from the collection, after 5 seconds, go back to the first View with the Start button. I tried with `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated` but it didn't work.

When I clic the Start button I call a nib with a identifier:

```
 self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToViewController", sender: nil)
```

This nib have a Custom Class asigned:

[image]

Inside this class, I develop the behavior of `PageViewController`, where I configure the `PageViewController` contents like a StoryboardID's:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class PageViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    var audioPagePlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    var error: NSError?
    var audioPage = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Turn page", ofType: "mp3")!)
    var contentPageRestorationIDs = [String]()
    var pageViewController = UIPageViewController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        audioPagePlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: audioPage, error: &error)

        contentPageRestorationIDs = ["FirstView", "SecondView", "ThirdView", "FourthView", "FiveView", "SixView", "SevenView", "EightView", "NineView", "TenView", "ElevenView", "TwelveView", "ThirteenView", "FourteenView"]
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageViewController") as UIPageViewController
        pageViewController.dataSource = self

        var startingController: UIViewController = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0)!

        pageViewController.setViewControllers([startingController], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

        self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController)
        self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
        self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)


    }

    func goToPreviousContentViewController(){

        var currentViewController: AnyObject = self.pageViewController.viewControllers[0]
        var vcRestorationID = currentViewController.restorationIdentifier
        var index = find(contentPageRestorationIDs, vcRestorationID!!)

        var previousViewController: UIViewController = self.viewControllerAtIndex(index! - 1)!

        pageViewController.setViewControllers([previousViewController], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Reverse, animated: false, completion: nil)



    }

    func goToNextContentViewController(){

        var currentViewController: AnyObject = self.pageViewController.viewControllers[0]
        var vcRestorationID = currentViewController.restorationIdentifier
        var index = find(contentPageRestorationIDs, vcRestorationID!!)

        var nextViewController: UIViewController = self.viewControllerAtIndex(index! - 1)!

        pageViewController.setViewControllers([nextViewController], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)



    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> (UIViewController?){
        var vcRestorationID = viewController.restorationIdentifier
        var index = find(contentPageRestorationIDs, vcRestorationID!)

        if(index == 0){
            return nil
        }

        audioPagePlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPagePlayer.play()


        return viewControllerAtIndex(index! - 1)
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> (UIViewController?){
        var vcRestorationID = viewController.restorationIdentifier
        var index = find(contentPageRestorationIDs, vcRestorationID!)

        if(index == contentPageRestorationIDs.count - 1){
            return nil
        }

        var vc = viewController as BaseContentViewController

        if(vc.goNext == true){

            audioPagePlayer.prepareToPlay()
            audioPagePlayer.play()

            return viewControllerAtIndex(index! + 1)

        }
        return nil
    }


    func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> (Int){
        return self.contentPageRestorationIDs.count
    }

    func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> (Int){
        return 0
    }


    func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int)-> (BaseContentViewController!) {

        if(index >= contentPageRestorationIDs.count){
            return nil
        }

        var storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType))

        var contentViewController: BaseContentViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(self.contentPageRestorationIDs[index]) as BaseContentViewController

        contentViewController.rootViewController = self

        contentViewController.loadView()

        return contentViewController

    }
}
```

The view controller of each nib extends from a custom class `BaseContentViewController`:

```
import UIKit

class BaseContentViewController: UIViewController {

    var rootViewController: PageViewController = PageViewController()
    var goNext = Bool()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        println("View Did Load Form Base Content View Controller")
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



}
```

When I'm in the View with de StoryboardID "FourteenView", after 5 seconds, I need to go back to the view before the PageViewController

Answer (score 1):

how you are showing PageViewController ? If you are pushing it then you have to pop it, and if you are presenting it as a model then use dismissViewControllerAnimated!!

Comment: When I push the Start Button, I call Storyboard with identifier "goToPageViewController".  This nib in the storyboard have a PageViewController like Class and use a PageViewControllerView for load each ViewController

Comment: Plz put in the code for the way you display the view controller after button is pressed

Comment: Ya, you are getting a view controller using identifier, but how you are presenting the controller ? use something like given below -(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    MyCustomViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];

   [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}   then use dismissViewControllerAnimated to go back after delay.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `performSelector` with delay like this

```
[self performSelector:@selector(functionToDismiss) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
```

where `functionToDismiss` should contain the code to dismiss your current view controller

Comment: Ok, but where can implament these function, in the PageViewController or in the last View??

Comment: when you say `the last item from the collection` what exactly do you mean... which collection?? TableView or CollectionView??

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

The solution is put inside a function this code a call after delay:

```
func finish(){

    self.rootViewController.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

}
```